# How can manage php session after successful logout?

Tags: php, cakephp

In my application has three web pages.
1.) login page.
2.) welcome page
3.) logout page

I have managed the session using PHP session object.
In my application log-In and log-Out functionality is working properly.

Here problem is that: After successful logout when user click on browser back button from logout.php page, again he reach to welcome.php page Whereas he log-Out successfully. But I want to there page has been expired or should not to come back welcome.php page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bit tricky, but (as far as I'm aware) this has something to do with cache.

I managed to avoid this particular problem by adding some headers through PHP:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

These should of course only be set when the user is logged in, as caching should be considered a good thing normally.

Comment: Hi Repox,
can you explan this line:
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
I think, this datetime should be less current datetime. right?

Comment: @vin This tells the browser that the content expired at that specific date (which is way back) - which essentielly is one of the ways to force a browser to not get the cached version of your content.

Comment: @vin Yes, basically - as long as the date is before that current time.

Comment: Hey Repox: One thing more, After successful registration user should not to comeback to registration form page. will it work for that?

Comment: @vin That would be related to your code logic and not the cache.

Answer (score 0):

you need to force it to refresh the page and not laod it from cache.

plus diffrent browsers handle this diffrently. try adding a second  section to your doc on the browse page

```
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you check the authentication on ur welcome page.

Example:

`if($_SESSION['authenticated'] = true)`
`include('welcome.php')`
`else`
`include('login.php)`

Another better application will be to redirect using Headers.
`header('Location: ' (LINK) );`

Comment: This will not force the browser to reload the page when you press the back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CakePHP 2, you can also just do

```
$this->response->disableCache();
```

that basically does the same thing than the answer given by Repox